# Typing a word that creates a number value in a different Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I was wondering if it was possible in excel to put a word in a cell and create a condition or formula where it affects other cells?

For example, in the cell underneath daily condition, I want to put the word CHOP and then that word reduces Cells A13-C13 by 50%. Is that possible?

[image: Sheet Picture]

Comment: In `A13` you could put `IF(D7="CHOP",0.5,1)*<formula currently in A13>`.  You could do something similar for `B13:C13` but you have to be careful if those cells refer to `A13`.

Comment: is there a way that i can string Chop to be cut 50% while putting MACRO 100%?

Comment: You should set up a lookup table for all the `daily conditions` and their corresponding impact such as 50%, 25%, etc. and then use **XLOOKUP** or **VLOOKUP** to fetch the percentage based on the daily condition entered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in A13

If(D7 = "CHOP",.5,IF("D7"="MACRO",1,0))